# Why are these generics being treated differently?

Tags: typescript

In the code below, why is it returning different results - when one defines a type, vs. entering the same type as a generic:

```js
type StrictEqual<A1, A2> = [A1] extends [A2] ? ([A2] extends [A1] ? true : false) : false
const typesMatch = <A, B>(match: StrictEqual<A, B>) => match
type Pins<N extends { x: 0 }> = () => N['x'];

type Foo = Pins<{ x: 0 }>
type Bar = Pins<{ x: 0, y: 1 }>
typesMatch<Foo, Bar>(true) // okay
typesMatch<Pins<{ x: 0 }>, Pins<{ x: 0, y: 1 }>>(true) // error
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=64&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAxsAogRwK4EMA2APAIICMANFEQEwB8UAvFANqkC6UEAHsBAHYAmAZ2bV2AfigAKFlXZceA4SxLioCLNABcUAGb5BEAJRRtevAYBQyAPa9BwNeAiCAsjmDIAFgyjEKAIRpJAFt3L204JFRMXEIiAJpjejpQj08LUEgoAAVEOwIAOQ5uPiEoAG8oTm0ABigAXzpGSSS6AqYAck4O1gBuCwynKAAxa2sfXPzK6qg6xsGs-xx4CbzBAmnaihBtEgaaBec3NIJR6wDloPUjKAB6W6hrAGscEEPXMM8CSfXN2f2KD8NlUtlAdlA9o0rvANMZ7hx4PBrPABkA)

Comment: Could you try to make the example more minimal?  Is everything here necessary to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I just spent the last 10 minutes producing [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDRJVW), which as far as I can tell demonstrates the same issue in a handful of short lines of code.  Could you please verify that this is the same thing and then [edit] your code to be minimal like this?  I think the answer here has to do with TS skipping structural checks in favor of quicker but less accurate variance hints, but I will come back later and look because right now I'm a bit drained from doing the [mre] part of the question.

Comment: All right, I wrote up an answer regardless.

Comment: @jcalz - wow amazing work - I've edited the question accordingly - apologies for the delay, life happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR TypeScript's type checker needs to make simplifying assumptions in order to be performant, and sometimes these assumptions are incorrect.  The `Pins` type function is incorrectly assumed to have measurable [variance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411491/2887218) (probably *invariant*).

When the compiler notices that it is comparing `Pins<A, C>` to `Pins<B, D>`, it simplifies this to a comparison of `A` to `B` and of `C` to `D` without evaluating `Pins` at all.  On the other hand, when it doesn't notice, it fully evaluates `Pins<A, B>` and `Pins<C, D>` and compares the results.

These are different ways of comparing types and can have different results, and so there is a tradeoff between correctness and performance, and you've run into a situation where this is manifested.

For more information, see [microsoft/TypeScript#39549](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39549), [microsoft/TypeScript#48116](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48116), [microsoft/TypeScript#49852](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49852) and probably many others.

---

Here is a minimal example of what you're seeing.  The following code compiles with no problem:

```
type Foo<T extends { x: 0 }> = () => T['x'];

type Bar = Foo<{ x: 0 }> // type Bar = () => 0
declare let bar: Bar;

type Baz = Foo<{ x: 0, y: 1 }> // type Baz = () => 0
let baz: Baz = bar; // okay
```

Which makes sense because both `Bar` and `Baz` are equivalent to `() => 0`.  But the following seemingly identical code has an error:

```
type Foo<T extends { x: 0 }> = () => T['x'];

declare let bar: Foo<{ x: 0 }>;

let baz: Foo<{ x: 0, y: 1 }> = bar; // error?!
// Type 'Foo<{ x: 0; }>' is not assignable to type 'Foo<{ x: 0; y: 1; }>'.
```

Why is `Foo<{x: 0}>` not assignable to `Foo<{x: 0, y: 1}>` if `Bar` *is* assignable to `Baz`?  Shouldn't the type checker recognize all of those types as `() => 0` which are [compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) with each other?

---

The answer is that it *should* be the same, but the TypeScript type checker can't afford to be fully consistent.  Let's say that type checker needs to determine if type `X` is assignable to type `Y`.  The *correct* thing to do would be to perform what's known as a full *structural check* where each member of `Y` is fully structurally checked against to each member of `X`... a recursive procedure which in the general case can be very expensive (if the types are complex and deep) or even undecidable (if the types are themselves recursive).  So sometimes, the compiler will need to skip the full check.

One way it does this is with so-called *variance markers*.  If the compiler notices that `X` is of the form `F<A>` and `Y` is of the form `F<B>`, then it might be able to skip the full check if the type parameter in `F<T>` has a variance marker.  For example, if `F<T>` is known to be *covariant* in `T`, then `F<A>` is assignable to `F<B>` if and only if `A` is assignable to `B`.  Which means the compiler can just check `A` against `B`, which is potentially easier to do.

If all type functions could be accurately marked as covariant, contravariant, bivariant, or invariant, then we could improve type checking performance without losing correctness.

Unfortunately this is not possible. Many type functions are complex enough that their variance doesn't fall into those neat categories; it might be that for arbitrary `A` and `B` you have no idea if `F<A>` is or is not assignable to `F<B>` without doing a full structural check.  In these cases, `F<T>` would need to also be marked as *unreliable* (you need to fall back to a structural check in cases where the variance check fails) or *unmeasurable* (you cannot rely on a variance check at all).

So now we have a trade-off. The spectrum runs from:

- Mark all type functions as having unmeasurable variance. All type checks would be full structural checks, and we'd have consistent behavior from a compiler with abysmal performance, to:
- Mark all type functions with a best-effort measurable variance. Full structural checks would rarely be performed, and we'd have a compiler that produces wrong results quickly.

Everywhere in the middle we have to perform some analysis to determine which type functions should have measurable variance, and this analysis would itself have a tradeoff between performance and correctness.

---

It's probably not too illuminating to do much digging to find out *exactly* where along this spectrum TypeScript is.  In the above example, `Foo<T>` seems to have been incorrectly marked as *covariant* in `T`, which is often a reasonable thing to do when you're using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  But in this case it leads to problems.  It would be great if the compiler had marked `Foo<T>` as unreliable or unmeasurable.  But could that happen without destroying performance either by doing too many unnecessary structural checks or by spending too much time deciding whether or not to do one?  I don't know.  From the GitHub issues linked above and others, it seems like messing with variance markers can easily lead to performance problems, so they tend to avoid doing that if they can.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFShAHsCA7AJgZygG8p0AuKABigF8A+KAXigAoBKJh5AbQHJ1eAXQBQw7AEMAthHxhxAY2gA1CACd8ASzjYAjMVFRDUUJCgAhcaqawEiEuSq0GAemfHw0C1ebtOVYUZQuBDyADaW0KEQwFAARpYUXgDcBkYmnuIAXtbwSPYUlAA0UCAUevRQru6mFtk+HIwMlAFGUTHxmYlZ1vGqSZVucADW4iCiNKIS0rIKymqa2gBM+i2GwWERUG1xCTZ5pAVOKatb0Tude3YHVMWlUOUMzL39VWqqcKoA-ACEJ1XIHigvFyVwclH69F4UA0hGwcBi4nwmgA5hJYlFjHBqtBgbZ8lR+ncdBC6LwAHTjUSiIA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it's much appreciated - it clarifies what is occurring and has deepened my understanding of typescript.